# skype chat bot not sending message in group

Tags: botframework, skype

I've just tried creating a very simple chat bot using node.js. I've gotten it working in the web app and also using one on one chat. As soon as I add it to the group though it doesn't respond to the messages. I've tried using the "@botname" with the message and without it, but it still doesn't work.

I've given it to some friends to test as well and they have the same issue. Works one on one but not in the group.

I haven't published the app but as far as I knew it wasn't necessary when only testing with less than 100 users.

Here is the code I'm using, it is in typescript but the compiled javascript still works.

```
import * as builder from 'botbuilder';
import * as restify from 'restify';
declare var process;

// Setup Restify Server
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, (session) => {
    const text = session.message.text;
    if(text.startsWith("#")) {
        // interpret roll
        const textAfterHash = text.substr(1);
        const value = Number(textAfterHash);
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            const rollArray: number[] = new Array<number>();
            let hits: number = 0;
            let misses: number = 0;
            for (let index = 0; index < value; index++) {
                let roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
                if (roll >= 5) {
                    hits++;
                } else{
                    misses++;
                }  
                rollArray.push(roll);          
            }
            const finalString = `Hits: ${hits} / Missses: ${misses}, Rolls: ${rollArray.join(",")}`
            session.send(finalString);       
        }
    }
});
```

Here are the dependencies for my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "^3.14.0",
    "restify": "^6.3.4",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So turns out I should have done some more debugging. When you use the @botname in the message it sends that text too so all you have to do is sanitize that part of the text and it all works :)